# How do I use grepl to filter out based off matches from a string of characters?

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a list of gene names that I am trying to filter out of a larger data set using grepl. For example:

```
gene_list <- c(geneA, geneB, geneC)
data <- c(XXXgene1, XXXgene2, XXXgeneF, XXXgeneA, XXXgeneB)
select_grepl <- data %>% filter(grepl(c(gene_list), data)==T)
```

I have tried the grepl code above but since the pattern is > 1 they only use the first geneA to search within the string. If I change c(gene_list) to a single pattern like "geneA", then the code works. Is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your keywords in `grepl` with a `|`. You can do this easily by using `paste(..., collapse = "|")` like below. Note that you need to transform your `data` vector that you gave as an example to a `data.frame` in order to apply the `filter()`. The following code works.

**Code**:

```
gene_list <- c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC")
data <- c("XXXgene1", "XXXgene2", "XXXgeneF", "XXXgeneA", "XXXgeneB")

gene_vec <- paste(gene_list, collapse = "|")
select_grepl <- as.data.frame(data) %>% 
                filter(., grepl(gene_vec, data) == TRUE)
```

**Output**:

```
> select_grepl
      data
1 XXXgeneA
2 XXXgeneB
```